# Rewiring of a vibration sensor

Tags: sensor, noise, vibration

Can I pass the signal of a (iepe) vibration sensor over a shielded twisted pair instead of the recommended coax cable?

The signal also needs to travel over 30-meter cable.

Comment: Who recommends coax? This application note recommends shielded twisted pair and that coax not be used in a permanent installation: https://wilcoxon.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/TN22_Vibration-Sensor-Wiring-and-Cabling-1.pdf (p. 10)

Comment: @user1714223: I don't think you can assume that many will know what an 'iepe' (all lower case?) sensor is. You should add a part number and datasheet link. If it is sending out a high-frequency signal you need to give details on that too.

Comment: @replete I actually saw small iepe vibration sensors being manufactured with coax connectors and sold with matching cables. Not an unusual choice.